# Issue Sending Mail via SMTP

Tags: smtp, imap, email-client, mailcore, mailcore2

My iOS application uses Mailcore to access a user's email account. Sending and receiving is done via SMTP and IMAP, and both processes work as expected for Gmail and Outlook (which both use OAuth for login).

I just added Yahoo (as well as some other providers to the app who do not use OAuth) and for all of these providers I am having an issue specifically with sending messages.

**The issue is that although messages DO get sent successfully from my application, they do not appear in the sent folder on the web for the provider.**

For example, if I log into my Yahoo account in my application, and send a message to my Gmail account, the message appears in my Gmail inbox on the web, but not in my Yahoo sent box on the web.

I tried adding Yahoo to the regular mail app on iPhone and sending a message from this account - this worked fine - the message shows up Yahoo sent box on the web. So, I then compared the headers of the two messages (the one sent from mail app and the one sent from my app) and the only obvious difference I see is in the line 'X-Rocket-Received':

Mail App:

```
X-Rocket-Received: from [11.180.250.219] (userName@71.208.72.234 with xymcookie [216.39.61.254])
    by smtp203.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with SMTP; 23 May 2014 08:19:54 -0700 PDT
```

My App:

```
X-Rocket-Received: from  (userName@118.41.27.139 with plain [98.138.105.21])
    by smtp214.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with SMTP; 23 May 2014 08:58:29 -0700 PDT
```

Can anyone answer any of the following questions for me:

1) What does X-Rocket-Received mean?

2) What is the significance of "with xymcookie" versus "with plain"?

3) Is my issue likely to do with my not having an xymcookie?

4) Where might I begin to solve this issue?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending an email with SMTP directly does not put the email in the provider's Sent folder.  You have to log into the provider with IMAP and put a copy of the email into the Sent folder as a separate operation.  Higher level apps, like iPhone's mail app, handle these details internally.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, the `APPEND` command is used to upload a copy of the email into the Sent folder via IMAP.

Comment: To add even more information: There are a few systems that *do* automatically place into the Sent box: gmail is one of them.  This is non-standard behaviour though.

Comment: @Max: Agreed. For example, GoDaddy does NOT automatically put an SMTP email in the Sent folder.

Answer (score 2):

Additional information:

1. It was placed there by some server along the way.  It is a non-standard header.  It appears similar to a standard SMTP Received header though.
2. 'xymcookie' is a non-standard authentication method used by Yahoo.  It is not, as far as I can tell, publicly documented.
3. No.
4. See Remy's answer.  Use IMAP Append for most servers.  Gmail does not require it, but that is non-standard.